# Is there a Rabbinical stance on "Ghost Hunting" and whether it is an allowable activity?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, sin, curse, danger

Strange topic but I was curious if anything existed in relation to it.

**"Ghost Hunting"** can be done for different reasons. Typically, it's in reference to paranormal investigators seeking evidence of paranormal activity or evidence of ghosts/spirits and so on. That being said, some folks just like to go looking for a ghost and don't really have a scientific pursuit attached to it.

My question is pretty straight forward.

Regardless of whether or not the idea of ghosts is endorsed, is there a Rabbinical stance on people meddling with spirits and ghosts in an investigative way?

From what I understand, the main issue would be communicating with the dead and even then the issue would be seeking knowledge from them. Are there other restrictions related to the dead that I'm not aware of which may tie into my question?

Is it Rabbinically problematic for a Jew to seek out ghosts in a "ghost hunt" situation?

Comment: The Torah prohibits involvement with “ghosts” as it says [Vayikro ]( https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.31?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en) 
Do not turn to ghosts and do not inquire of familiar spirits, to be defiled by them: I the LORD am your God.
The Ibn Ezra comments
Do not seek to request their services (as Saul did [I Samuel 28:8](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.28?lang=bi)).

So it seems that the main prohibition is to use the ghosts to inquire from them. It could be that without seeking to inquire, there may not be a Torah prohibition. Of Rabbinic views, I know not.